# Blazored.Modal.BlazoredModal' does not have a property matching the name 'ChildContent'

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor-webassembly

I have index.razor page which contains 3 sections when I click on Medication section It will open the table data .In that table I have a Edit button When I click on edit button I am unable to open popup getting error as following(I am doing this uisng blazor webassembly)

```
Unhandled exception rendering component: Object of type 'Blazored.Modal.BlazoredModal' does not have a property matching the name 'ChildContent'.
System.InvalidOperationException: Object of type 'Blazored.Modal.BlazoredModal' does not have a property matching the name 'ChildContent'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.ThrowForUnknownIncomingParameterName(Type targetType, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.SetProperties(ParameterView& parameters, Object target)
```

I am giving my code files below

```
@page "/"
@using System.Net.Http
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@inject HttpClient HttpClient
@using System.Text.Json;
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
@using Blazored
@using Blazored.Modal
@using Blazored.Modal.Services
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@using Microsoft.JSInterop;

@inject IModalService ModalService

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Your Blazor App</title>
    <!-- Other head content goes here -->
    <!-- Add the following line to link your CSS file -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />


</head>




<div class="container">
    <div class="sticky-buttons">
        <div class="button-container">
            <div class="button-row" id="tooltip-container">
                <button id="button-general" class="custom-btn @(activeTableIndex == 1 ? "active" : "")" @onclick="() => ShowTable(1)">************</button>
            </div>
            <div class="button-row">
                <button id="button-allergies" class="custom-btn @(activeTableIndex == 2 ? "active" : "")" @onclick="() => ShowTable(2)">***************</button>
            </div>
            <div class="button-row">
                <button id="button-medications" class="custom-btn @(activeTableIndex == 3 ? "active" : "")" @onclick="() => ShowTable(3)">Medications</button>
            </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Add similar buttons for other sections -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="table-section">
        @if (activeTableIndex == 1)
        {
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>General Information</th>
                        <!-- Add more columns as needed -->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- Add table data here -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
        else if (activeTableIndex == 2)
        {
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Allergies</th>
                        <!-- Add more columns as needed -->
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- Add table data here -->
                </tbody>
            </table>
        }
        else if (activeTableIndex == 3)
        {
            <div class="section">
                <label class="section-label">Medications</label>
            </div>
            <table class="section-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Medication/Strength</th>
                        <th>Route</th>
                        <th>Frequency</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>Prescription</th>
                        <th>Refill</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var medication in medications)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td class="dynamic">@medication.MedicationStrength</td>
                            <td class="dynamic">@medication.Route</td>
                            <td class="dynamic">@medication.Frequency</td>
                            <td class="dynamic">@medication.Quantity</td>
                            <td class="dynamic">@medication.Prescription</td>
                            <td class="dynamic">@medication.Refill</td>
                            <td class="dynamic">
                                <button class="accept-btn">Accept</button>
                                <button class="edit-btn" @onclick="() => OpenEditModal(medication)">Edit</button>
                                <button class="discard-btn">Discard</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                </tbody>

            </table>
         
            
            <!-- Modal for the edit popup -->
        }


    </div>
</div>
 <BlazoredModal>
                <EditMedicationModal EditModalContent="">
                    <ChildContent>
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Medication</h5>

                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">
                                <label for="medicationStrength"><b>Medication Strength</b></label>
                                <input type="text" id="medicationStrength" @bind="@selectedMedicationForEdit.MedicationStrength" class="form-control" />

                                <label for="route"><b>Route</b></label>
                                <input type="text" id="route" @bind="selectedMedicationForEdit.Route" class="form-control" />

                                <label for="frequency"><b>Frequency</b></label>
                                <input type="text" id="frequency" @bind="selectedMedicationForEdit.Frequency" class="form-control" />

                                <label for="quantity"><b>Quantity</b></label>
                                <input type="text" id="quantity" @bind="selectedMedicationForEdit.Quantity" class="form-control" />

                                <label for="prescription"><b>Prescription</b></label>
                                <input type="text" id="prescription" @bind="selectedMedicationForEdit.Prescription" class="form-control" />

                                <label for="refill"><b>Refill</b></label>
                                <input type="text" id="refill" @bind="selectedMedicationForEdit.Refill" class="form-control" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="CloseModal">Cancel</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="UpdateMedicationModal">Update</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ChildContent>
                </EditMedicationModal>
                </BlazoredModal>

@code {
    private int activeTableIndex = 0;
    private string[] tableNames = { "General Information", "Allergies", "Medications" }; // Add more table names

    private string activeTableName => activeTableIndex >= 0 && activeTableIndex < tableNames.Length
        ? tableNames[activeTableIndex]
        : "";

    private void ShowTable(int tableIndex)
    {
        activeTableIndex = tableIndex;
    }
}



@code {
    private List<Medication> medications = new List<Medication>();

    private Medication selectedMedicationForEdit = new Medication();
    private bool isEditModalOpen = false;
    private EditMedicationModal editModal;
    //private bool isEditModalOpen = false;

    private async Task LoadMedications()
    {
        // Replace this with your API call and response handling
        var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync("http://localhost:****/api/*****?id=********");
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        // Deserialize the API response JSON
        var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(responseContent);
        Console.WriteLine(apiResponse);

        // Extract the value from the specified path and populate the medications list
        foreach (var item in apiResponse)
        {
            
            var medication = new Medication
                {
                    MedicationStrength = item["resourceType"],
                    Route = item["id"],
                    Frequency = item["type"],
                    Quantity = item["resourceType"],
                    Prescription = "outpatient",
                    Refill = "Yes",
                   
                };
            if (medication.Prescription == "outpatient" || medication.Prescription == "community")
            {
                medication.Prescription = "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                medication.Prescription = "No";
            }

            medications.Add(medication);
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await LoadMedications();
    }
 
 
    private async Task OpenEditModal(Medication medication)
    {
        selectedMedicationForEdit = medication;
        var parameters = new ModalParameters();
        parameters.Add(nameof(EditMedicationModal.SelectedMedication), selectedMedicationForEdit);

        var modalInstance = ModalService.Show<EditMedicationModal>("Edit Medication", parameters);
        var result = await modalInstance.Result;
    }

    private void UpdateMedicationModal()
    {
        isEditModalOpen = false;
    }
    private void CloseModal()
    {
       // isEditModalOpen = false;
    }
   
    
 
    // Medication class definition
    public class Medication
    {
        public string MedicationStrength { get; set; }
        public string Route { get; set; }
        public string Frequency { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Prescription { get; set; }
        public string Refill { get; set; }
        
    }



}
```

EditMedicationmodal.razor

```
@page "/editmedicationmodal"
@using Blazored.Modal
@using SmartApp.Pages
@using static SmartApp.Pages.Index

<BlazoredModal @ref="modalInstance">
    <div class="@modalClass" tabindex="-1" style="display: @displayMode;">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Medication</h5>
                    <button class="close" @onclick="CloseModal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    @ChildContent
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="CloseModal">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</BlazoredModal>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
    [CascadingParameter] public BlazoredModalInstance Modal { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Medication SelectedMedication { get; set; }

    // Add any other properties and methods you need

    private BlazoredModal modalInstance;
    private string modalClass => IsOpen ? "modal fade show" : "modal fade";
    private string displayMode => IsOpen ? "block" : "none";
    private bool IsOpen { get; set; }

    private void CloseModal()
    {
        IsOpen = false;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    //private async Task CloseEditPopup()
    //{
    //    await OnUpdate.InvokeAsync();
    //}
    //private async Task UpdateMedication()
    //{
    //    // Implement your update logic here

    //    // Close the modal
    //    await CloseEditPopup();
}
```

Can anyone please help on it
Thanks

Comment: Could you please kindly check the solution below ? If you have fixed the issue, you also can share with us.

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that class BlazoredModal does not contain property “ChildContent”. When using tag  and initialing a  instance, it won’t find “ChildContent” in class BlazoredModal.
We can use class CascadingBlazoredModal which contains property “ChildContent”. The tag  is not necessary in the page part in index.razor. At the same time, EditMedicationModal contains child html content, so it is necessary to declare the property "EditModelContent".

[The document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHH0t.png)

[image: The document]

Here is the code.

index.razor:

```
<CascadingBlazoredModal>
    <EditMedicationmodal EditModelContent="">
        <div class="modal-content">
        ...
        </div>
    </EditMedicationmodal>
</CascadingBlazoredModal>
```

EditMedicationmodal.razor:

```
<CascadingBlazoredModal @ref="modalInstance">
    <div class="@modalClass" tabindex="-1" style="display: @displayMode;">
    ...
    </div>
</CascadingBlazoredModal>

@code {
[CascadingParameter] public BlazoredModalInstance Modal { get; set; }
[Parameter, EditorRequired] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
[Parameter, EditorRequired] public String? EditModelContent { get; set; }
[Parameter] public Medication SelectedMedication { get; set; }

// Add any other properties and methods you need

private CascadingBlazoredModal modalInstance;
private string modalClass => IsOpen ? "modal fade show" : "modal fade";
private string displayMode => IsOpen ? "block" : "none";
private bool IsOpen { get; set; }

...
}
```